# Can I overload operators for builtin classes in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, overloading, built-in

Is it possible to overload an operator for a builtin class in Python 3? Specifically, I'd like to overload the `+`/`+=` (i.e: `__add__` operator for the `str` class, so that I can do things such as `"This is a " + class(bla)`.

Comment: Do you actually mean *overload* (i.e. you're subclassing `str`) or do you actually want to monkey patch? Why not use `str.format`, rather than hacking your way to unreadable code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change `str`'s `__add__`, but you *can* define how to add your class to strings. I don't recommend it, though.

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return str(self) + other
        ...
    def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return other + str(self)
        ...
```

In `"asdf" + thing`, if `"asdf".__add__` doesn't know how to handle the addition, Python tries `thing.__radd__("asdf")`.

Comment: worked, thanks :). one question though - why don't you recommend it?

Comment: @Joe: Pretty much nothing else auto-converts to a string when you add it to a string. The Python convention is to do string conversion explicitly.

Comment: @Joe I think a better question is why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: @IanAuld really just to make it a bit simpler for the user

Comment: @Joe The more standard thing in python is to implement `__str__` or `__repr__` for your class, so that the user can do `"This is a " + str(bla)`